# How to check if instance entity has been modify in the view?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, audit

I need a guide here.
Let's say that I'm fetching some records from db an I'm populating a ui datatable with those records.

The datatable can modify the values of the records as its columns are inputs.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{videogames.videogameList}" var="vg"  >
        <p:column headerText="Name">
            <p:inputText value="#{vg.name}" />
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

How can I know if some row was modify in order to update the value in the database?

Should I check each element in the list and compare it to a temporal arraylist with the original values? Is there a more "elegant" way to do this?

Do you know any tutorial or docs that can help me to learn all this.

Thanks!

I am working with Java, JSF, primafaces and JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution for this case.

What I did, was to add an ajax listener with **event="change"**, to the inputtext that can modify the value of the row, so everytime the value changes, the listener will pass the row as a param to a method, and the method will add the row to a list:

videogames.xhtml

```
    <p:column headerText="Nombre">
        <p:inputText value="#{vj.nombre}">
           <!--this is the added listener-->
           **<f:ajax event="change" listener="#{videojuegos.rowSelectedTest(vj)}" />**
        </p:inputText>
    </p:column>

   <!-- **Button that calls the method for updating the modify entities columns**-->
   <p:commandButton  value="Actualizar" actionListener="#{videojuegos.updateVideojuego()}"/>
```

The managed bean receives it, and adds it to a list:

VideoGamesManagedBean.java

```
 List  <Videojuego> videojuegoUpdate = new ArrayList<Videojuego>();
//adds the modify row to a list
public void rowSelectedTest(Videojuego videojuego){
     videojuegoUpdate.add(videojuego);
 }

//calls the method in the EJB for merging each object in the list
public void updateVideojuego(){

     if(videojuegoUpdate != null && !videojuegoUpdate.isEmpty() ){
        vjbean.mergeVideojuegoList(videojuegoUpdate);
         //after merging, cleans up the arraylist.
         videojuegoUpdate.clear();
     }
 }
```

and last, the EJB iterates through the list and merge each object

VideoGameBean.java

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public void mergeVideojuegoList(List<Videojuego> listVideojuegoUpdate){
   for(Videojuego vjUpdate : listVideojuegoUpdate ){
       em.merge(vjUpdate);
   }
```

}

**NOTE:**

*the only "problem" for this is, if I modify several times the same column before I hit the commandbutton "Actualizar", the list will grow up with the same row. But the merge method will take the last "version" of the column.* So for our needs, it is ok.

Thanks for the previous answers, regards!!

If you know any better method or find any corner case, let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could post it as a comment, but I lack the rep for it. I hope it serves as an answer (since you've asked for sources to learn it).

I work with PrimeFaces as well, but personally I haven't dealt with editable rows yet. Skimming over the links I give below, what you want should be doable with a **RowEditEvent**.

The PrimeFaces showcase is sort of a tutorial in and of itself. Here is the link for editable datatables:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

Navigate through the xhtml and .java examples. It should bootstrap you in the right direction.

PrimeFaces documentation is a great source of info as well:

http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf

Comment: row edit does not have any indication whether the actual data has changed or not...

Answer (score 0):

There is an Ajax event called `rowEdit` that should help you. There is complementing event called `rowEditCancel` to detect when the user backs out of an edit.

The primefaces website offers a user guide that goes into a fair amount of detail for data tables and the rest of the framework. This is the link for the latest version 5.3.

[primefaces 5.3 users guide](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf)

Comment: row edit does not have any indication whether the actual data has changed or not...